# Sum of Infinite Series $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/16 + \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Everyone knows about the classic 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^i} = 1 $$
However, is there any way to find
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^{2^i}} = \dfrac12 + \dfrac14 + \dfrac{1}{16} + \dfrac{1}{256} + \cdots $$

Comment: okay i edited the post

Comment: Well, it's irrational for sure... I doubt there's any way to name this infinite sum that is more clear or concise than the sum itself.

Comment: In fact, it's [transcendental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental) (look for Fredholm number). As such, it's unlikely to have any "nicer" expression, just as @DanShved suggested.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276892/power-series-summation-formula

Comment: Transcendentality follows immediately from Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Why do you think it's different than a geometric series?

Comment: Do you want to show it converges or are you looking for what it converges to?

Comment: It is easy to show the sum converges. Giving a closed form for that value is an entirely different matter.

Comment: A fairly common keyword is "lacunary series", or "gap series" to google for. It has been a nice exercise (I think) in the beginning of the 20'th century to prove transcendentality of that number ...

Comment: See also:
[How to find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2137685),
[How to sum this series to infinity: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{2^{2^n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/788772).

Comment: Perhaps an interesting additional input about generalizations and especially the  *alternating* gap/lacunary series http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/mo/MO_Lacunaryseries.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Fredholm number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental) as pointed out in the comments, but in case you are interested in the numerical value, a quick *Mathematica* calculation reveals the sum is approximately $0.816422$.

Answer (score 5):

The sum mentioned by the OP, and sums like it, are in general very difficult to deal with. The OP's series is actually called the Fredholm number, and is transcendental (see the Wikipedia page for [Transcendental number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number)).

Note: This constant is also known as [Kempner's number](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1685) (not to be confused with the [Kempner series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series)!).

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^{a^k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{-a^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-a^k\log(a)}$$
Let's choose the seemingly simple example $a=e$ to get rid of the logarithm. We then get the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-e^k}$$
Now, Wolfram Alpha can't tackle it, nor can Mathematica. Given that this is a simple example of what this sort of sum looks like, I'm betting that no known, simple closed form exists. If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me though. I would be pleasantly surprised.