# Summation of $2^{(-2^{n})}$

Tags: summation, power-towers

By the ratio test, I know that this series convernges: $\sum2^{(-2^{n})}$, in the limit $n$ goes to infinity. Probably to something close to $.8$ (if not equal to $.8$). The problem is, how do I demonstrate it? or to what does it really converge? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{(-2^{n})}$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{(-2^{n})}$ ?

Comment: If the series converge, what's the difference between the two expressions?

Comment: @Spock In the first series the summatio is over $n$ and in the second its over $k$, so the second would simplify to $\lim n2^{(-2^n)}$

Comment: I think he means the first one, the second converges to $0$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583472/sum-of-infinite-series-1-1-2-1-4-1-16-cdots

Comment: Yes, it is the same question as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583472/sum-of-infinite-series-1-1-2-1-4-1-16-cdots. Thanks