# How to find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis

How can we handle sums of the type:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2^n}}$$ It is different from geometric series. Is there any general approach to deal such sums?

Comment: See also:
[Sum of Infinite Series $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/16 + \cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/583472),
[How to sum this series to infinity: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{2^{2^n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/788772).