# Is there any formula to sum the series $\sum_{k=1}^n{2^{k^k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, power-towers

$$\sum_{k=1}^n{2^{k^k}}$$

I couldn't find anything on this with a simple Google search so is it not trivial? If yes then can someone link some resources/Wikipedia page where I could read more? (can't find myself since I don't know the name of this)

Comment: For an approximate answer, just take the last term.  The terms grow so fast that the next to last is negligible by comparison with the last.  For example, at $n=10$ we have $2^{10^{10}}\approx 10^{3010299966}$ is too large for Alpha to do, but  $2^{9^9} \approx 10^{116625118}$

Comment: Related: [Sum of the form $r+r^2+r^4+\dots+r^{2^k} = \sum_{i=1}^k r^{2^i}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276892/13130)