# Is there a "hyper-geometric" or "super-geometric" sum formula?

Tags: analysis, summation, closed-form, rate-of-convergence

I know that when dealing with sums of the form $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n q^k$ with $q\neq 1$ we have the formula $S_n= \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$. But is there a known closed formula for a sum $S_n':=\sum_{k=1}^n q^{q^k}$?

Does anyone know of a solution or a useful relevant concept? I have a feeling that I am simply overlooking a simple solution here.

**Later edit**

Following the comments, I realize that there is no known closed formula for the sum. I was wondering however whether there are effective estimates on the sum. Specifically, how does the tail part of the sum behaves. If we take $n\ll N$, are there good estimates on  $\frac{S_{n}'}{S_N'}$?

I Think that this term should converge to zero very quickly.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no known closed form. Even in the case , say , $q=2$.

Comment: Neither Wolfram Alpha nor Mathematica come up with a closed formula.

Comment: Note that "hypergeometric" already has a couple standard meanings, e.g. [series/functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series) and [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: See [Sum of the form $r+r^2+r^4+\dots+r^{2^k} = \sum_{i=1}^k r^{2^i}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276892/13130).