# Variants of geometric sum formula

Tags: summation, power-series, closed-form, geometric-series, elementary-functions

I know there are closed formulas for sums of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n k^sr^k$
and $\sum_{k=0}^n r^{2n}$ or $\sum_{k=0}^n r^{2n+1}$.
(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)

From [Sum of the form $r+r^2+r^4+\dots+r^{2^k} = \sum_{i=1}^k r^{2^i}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276892/sum-of-the-form-rr2r4-dotsr2k-sum-i-1k-r2i) it seems that there is no closed formula known for sums of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n r^{2^k}$, or more generally $\sum_{k=0}^n r^{s^k}$

I'm wondering about sums of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n r^{(k^2)}$, or more generally
$\sum_{k=0}^n r^{(k^s)}$.
Does anyone know of a formula for those sums?

A closed formula for me would mean the number of arithmetical operations it uses is not depending on $n$ and it uses only elementary functions (whatever that means to you).

Does anyone have an idea how one could prove there is no such formula?

Comment: I doubt there exist closed forms for those sums. However, you can get reasonanly good lower and upper bounds by comparing them to integrals of form $\int e^{\ln(r) x^s} \ \mathrm{d}x$ and solve the integral by substituting $t = x^s$ which will give you result in form of Gamma function.